# var myvalue = window.opener.document.getElementById(“parentId1”) is not working

Tags: javascript, html

I was trying to get the value from my child.jsp to my parent.jsp using

```
var myvalue = window.opener.document.getElementById(“parentId1”)
```

Even though there were no errors found in the console the value is not getting in the parent page.

The child popup window has the url starting like, `https://host.example.com:7001/...`.. and the parent page url is different starts with `http://anotherhost:8080/webapp`.... is there any issue in communicating with a child window and a parent page which is on another server?

If so how can I solve this issue?

Comment: I've removed the `java` and `jsp` tags; this question has nothing to do with the server-side technology being used.

Comment: That didn't give you any errors?! `“parentId1”` will throw *SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL*. You have to use `"` or `'` to delimit string literals.

Comment: @Quentin where to look for the error message.

Comment: In the JavaScript console.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ...is there any issue in communicating with a child window and a parent page which is on another server?

Yes, this is prevented by the browser's implementation of the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

If you control both servers, look at using [Cross Origin Resource Sharing](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/).

Alternately, if you control the JavaScript code on the pages but not the servers (or just if you prefer this mechanism), you can use `postMessage` to send messages from one window to another. You can't directly access the other window's elements as in your code snippet, but the two pages can *cooperate* to deliver the relevant value from one page to another, even cross-origin. More on `postMessage`: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.postMessage) | [Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/webmessaging/)

Unless you can use CORS or `postMessage`, I don't think you can do it client-side; you'll need a proxy.

Comment: thanks for reply. so how can i solve this issue. any suggestions.

Comment: @user3148715: I moved the CORS stuff into the answer, and also add a note about `postMessage` (the thing Quentin mentioned in a comment).